# Ubuntu 16.04 connects to Wifi, but no internet connection

Tags: networking, internet

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 and since then, whenever I connect to a Wifi network, I get a "connection established" notification from Network Manager, but when I try to access any website, I get a "no internet access" message. I've looked for this problem being solved already and there is nothing concrete. Please help.

This is the output of    lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.